# .htaccess redirecting with two domains

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have two registered domains that redirect to the same hosting package. So, as an example I have the following two domains:

- www.domain1.com (Attached to the hosting)
- www.domain2.com (just redirects to www.domain1.com)

Both go to the same index page.

However, I would like to change this so that surfing to www.domain1.com would make you stay on the default index file and that surfing to www.domain2.com (or without the www) would make you go to a seperate folder (example www.domain1.com/domain2)

I'm guessing manipulating the .htaccess file is the way to go?

Comment: When do you go to the *same folder*? After the *same index page*?

Comment: No, just standard, after surfing to either of those domains it takes you to the standard public_html folder

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain2.com
RewriteRule ^index.html index2.html
```

Not sure what your default index file is, but you can edit the Rule to match.